# GoDaddy API - Bulk check for domains availibility issue

Tags: godaddy-api

I am trying to check the availibility of multiple domain at once according to the documentation here : https://developer.godaddy.com/doc#!/_v1_domains/available

```
POST: https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains/available
Body
{
  "domains": [
    "domain1.com",
    "domain2.com"
  ],
  "checkType": "fast"
}
Output
{
   "code":"INVALID_BODY",
   "message":"Request body doesn't fulfill schema, see details in `fields`",
   "fields":[
      {
         "message":"does not conform to the 'domain' format, based on pattern: /^[^.]{1,63}(\\.[^.]{1,63})+$/",
         "path":"domain[0]",
         "code":"MISMATCH_FORMAT"
      }
   ]
}
```

Would anyone know what's wrong with my request ?

Thank you

---

It happens that the expected body was a string array, no json
body: '["a.com","b.com"]'

In ruby: `['a.com', 'b.com'].to_json`

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint :

`POST v1/domains/available`

Takes a flat array:

`["1","2"...]`

Not an associative array:

`["domains": ["1","2"...] ]`

I hope this solves your issue!

Comment: p.s. the checkType variable is a route parameter on this endpoint, not part of the body: `POST v1/domains/available?checkType=FAST`